# PROGRESS 4GL Freeze after APPLY "Enter"

Tags: handle, progress-4gl

I update some fields with external procedure ( i cannot modify base program ) .

I try to jump over field I need, but on one, my program is freezing.
The procedure looks like that:

```
   PAUSE 0 NO-MESSAGE.

    IF FOCUS = field1
    THEN DO:
        field1:screen-value    = ''.
        APPLY 'ENTER' .
        PAUSE 0 .
    END. 

    IF FOCUS = field2
    THEN DO:
        field2:screen-value       = 'U'.
        APPLY 'ENTER' .
        PAUSE 0 .
    END.     

    IF FOCUS = field3
    THEN DO:
        field3:screen-value       = 'N'.
        APPLY 'ENTER' .
        PAUSE 0 .
        APPLY 'ENTER' .
        PAUSE 0.
    END.  

    PAUSE 0.
```

I put PAUSE 0, because its solve similiar case when I was in field2, but in field3 its not working.
What others step I can make?
Thank You for answers.
Regards.

e: When i said "Freeze" i mean Its waiting for any key. After 'any key' it goes onwards. 
Its problem, because i neet to automatize evrything .

e: And now i guess its not after APPLY statement but in some moment when i jumping over the fields. When i normally use the original program this freeze/waiting for key is unseen. So what in the code above can cause such an effect?

e: Its after APPLY "ENTER" on specific fields. Not for evry but some fields causes freezing ( not with Press Space message ). Pause 0 not working for them.

e: After using only this code :

```
IF FOCUS = field1 
THEN DO: 
     APPLY 'ENTER' .  
     APPLY 'COMPLETE' TO FOCUS. 
     PAUSE 0.
     MESSAGE 'dfdfd' VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.
END.
```

Its freezing after showing the message. Dont know why...

Comment: Chances are the "entry" event in this code is triggering the original "entry" trigger to fire again, which is why you're in an infinite loop.

Comment: Im sure its not loop. Its not freezing permanent. Its only stop and waiting only for space bar ( but its not "Press space bar..." message )  . And its not doing on all fields but only on few. Rest of fields are working normally. And this is only event on all of this fields.

Comment: In which case I'll need to see sample program which demonstrates this behavior.

Comment: I'm sorry Tim, I cant give You demonstrate.

Comment: I'm sorry Tim, I cant give You demonstrate with original program bu t i will try to build one with that effect.

Comment: I don't need the original code, just something that demonstrates the issue so I can look at it on my machine. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You've applied "enter".  So your code must RETURN NO-APPLY or it is going to undo the application of ENTER.

Comment: Thank You for answer. Unfortunately It doesn't help. I think that maybe original program is starting external procedure with some conflict parameter.